# Detect max extreme peaks/valleys with min 5% vertical delta

Tags: time-series, scipy

I have been using `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` but I'm not getting the desired results. My goal is to: identify the peaks/valleys in a 1D timeseries that are a minimum of 5% away from the prior peak/valley.

[image]

The following snippet computes the extreme peak/valleys with order of 15:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1000 + np.cumsum(0.1 + np.random.randint(-10, 10, 1000)), columns=['close'])
min_peaks = argrelextrema(df["close"].values, np.less, order=15)[0]
max_peaks = argrelextrema(df["close"].values, np.greater, order=15)[0]
```

However, this is not achieving my goals because: I want to identify the soonest peak/valley that is a minimum of 5% away from the prior peak/valley.

Whereas `argrelextrema` imposes a horizontal window (order) parameter - I don't have any constraint of horizontal distance. I only care that the peaks/valleys identified are a min of 5% away from the prior peak/valley.

UPDATE: An example for illustration:

- A peak is identified at 1000
- The next valley that can be identified must be >1050 or < 950.
- It is ok for two valleys (or peaks) to be identified in succession (same as with `argrelextrema`). You can see examples in the attached chart.

TY for any pointers/guidance in advance. LMK if/where I can add more detail in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by 5% of the previous peak/valley? For instance, if a peak is at 1000, you want to detect the next peak that is greater than 1050 or lower than 950, is it correct?

Comment: Correct @NicolasMartin - I added some extra detail to the question. I'd also add that is is ok for there to be two valleys (or peaks) identified in succession. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following zigzag python library provides this ability.

https://github.com/jbn/ZigZag/